# Central differences algorithm with Numpy

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I'm trying to implement a fairly simple algorithm with Numpy to numerically solve a system of differential equations. I works nicely with the so-called Euler forward method (i.e. the solution is the expected exponential decay), but it produces funny results with the [central differences](https://dmpeli.math.mcmaster.ca/Matlab/Math4Q3/NumMethods/Lecture3-1.html) scheme (see red and green curves in the figure below, compared to the orange and blue).

[image]

I suspect it might have to do with the way Numpy (and more generally Python) handles the assignation (whether it is just a name, whether it is past by reference, whether the slice notation, or a `np.copy()` should be used, etc.). To be honest I have read several articles on this topic but it still puzzles me (I'm a newcomer from Fortran).

A simplified version of the code I'm using and that reproduces the figure above is the following.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 100
Dt = 10 / N
t = np.linspace(0, 10, N+1)

y1 = np.zeros(N+1)
y2 = np.zeros(N+1)

##########################################
# problem definition (the result is an exponential decay)
y1[0] = 1
y2[0] = 2

def f(y):
    return -0.1 * y
##########################################



fig, ax = plt.subplots()

##########################################
# Euler-forward
y = np.ones(2)
y[0] = y1[0]
y[1] = y2[0]

for i in range(1, N+1):
    y = y + f(y) * Dt
    y1[i] = y[0]
    y2[i] = y[1]

ax.plot(t, y1)
ax.plot(t, y2)
##########################################


##########################################
# central differences
y = np.ones(2)
y[0] = y1[0]
y[1] = y2[0]

# first step is Euler-forward
y_new = y + f(y) * Dt
y_old = y
y = y_new

y1[1] = y[0]
y2[1] = y[1]

for i in range(2, N):
    f = np.cos(y)
    y_new = y_old + 2 * f * Dt
    y_old = y
    y = y_new
    y1[i] = y[0]
    y2[i] = y[1]

ax.plot(t, y1)
ax.plot(t, y2)
##########################################
```

Comment: The assignments do seem problematic, but can you elaborate a bit more on your _specific issue_ with an example?

Comment: You say there is an issue, but what is the issue? Better yet, can you replicate the issue with something simpler? It seems that you have an idea of what it is already. You should test out if you can at least isolate the problem, if not fix it.

Comment: I have now reformulated the question with a simpler version of the problem.